# make drop down and be aligned on the right side

Tags: css, menu

I'm using this drop-down menu and it comes down aligned with the button on the left but I want it to come down the opposite way because it's going off the screen on mobile. I attached pictures to show what it is doing vs what I am trying to make it do.

```
<div class='dropdown'>
  <button class='dropbtn'>Hi, Anthony &#9660;</button>
  <div class='dropdown-content'>
  <a href='index.php?c=my-profile'>My Golfer Profile</a>
  <a href='index.php?c=my-schedule'>My Schedule</a>
  <a href='index.php?c=account-settings'>Account Settings</a>
  <div style='width:100%;border-bottom: 1px #000 dotted;'>&nbsp;</div>
  <a href='actions/logout.php'>Logout</a>
  </div>
</div>


.dropbtn {
  background-color: #3D5C7F;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #3D5C7F;
}
```

[what it does](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdSYo.png)

[image]

[what I need it to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6RMw.png)

[image]

Comment: Could you please post your HTML as well it will help to provide a solution. Thanks.

Comment: sorry, it wouldn't let me add too much code when I originally posted.It let me edit it tho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you do not posted your HTML code I don't know which class is applied on your dropdown's starting element. If `dropdown-content` class is applied on the dropdown's starting element add the following styles along with the styles you already applied on the class `dropdown-content`:

```
.dropdown-content {
    right: 0;
    left: auto;
}
```

If you will post your HTML as well we could better help.

Comment: yeah i tried posting the code but it wouldn't let me post saying it contained too much code lol.

Comment: @TonyWierdman I run through the code with my suggestions and it's working for me could you please check and update me.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which class that is so I will give you an idea. The way I do it is that I position the dropdown absolute and position the parent element relative. When you do this , you can give it top and sides. In order to achive your position .. If you put the relative position to your whole navigation and dropdown will be absolute, you can give the dropdown something like `top: 40px` , `right: -30px` ... Hope this makes sense , if not , post some HTML and we will make it work.